# Euler Lagrange example

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, euler-lagrange-equation

Consider the Lagrangian $L:\mathbb{R}^2\times \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$

$$ L(\sigma,\dot{\sigma}):=\Big\langle \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{h} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\dot{\sigma}+ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & \frac{1}{h} \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\sigma,\dot{\sigma} \Big\rangle  $$

Note we know the boundary values as $\sigma(0)=(q,p)$ and $\sigma(1)=(q',p')$. I calculated the Euler Lagrange equations as

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -\frac{1}{h} \\ \frac{1}{h} & 0 \end{pmatrix}\dot{\sigma} -2\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{h} & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\ddot{\sigma}=0.$$

From here how do I access $\sigma$? can I solve these equations? If so how?

Comment: First reduce the order with a substitution $s=\dot{\sigma}$. Then compare this to an analogous ODE: $$ax-b\dot{x}=0$$ How would you solve this? With this in mind use the [matrix exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)